# Move docker images from one acr to another (docker images --format option not executing docker tag , docker push )

Tags: docker, docker-image, acr, docker-push, docker-tag

I am trying to move images from one acr to another acr. (also any alternate method to do this please suggest)

I am using shell script and
I have declared variables for one image to test it ( however i have 20+ images )
"sourceacr"
image="myimage"
minimum_version="1.0.0"
"targetacr"

steps followed:

```
docker pull $sourceacr/image --all-tags
```

then filter since the minimum version , re-tag it and push to target acr

my command is

```
docker images $sourceacr/$image --filter "since=$sourceacr/$image:$minimum_version" --format "docker tag {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} $targetacr/$image:{{.Tag}} | docker push $targetacr/$image:{{.Tag}}"
```

I get output as command that is used after --format option but it doesn't execute the tag and push commands. Any help is appreciated!

current output:

```
docker tag source.azurecr.io/myimage:1.0.0 target.azureacr.io/myimage:1.0.0 | docker push target.azureacr.io/myimage:1.0.0
```

Comment: Have you tried using xargs to take in standard input and give it as an argument to docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your command, it's basically outputting the docker commands in the terminal. You need to execute them as command, try like this:

```
docker images $sourceacr/$image  --filter "since=$sourceacr/$image:$minimum_version" --format "docker tag {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} $targetacr/$image:{{.Tag}} | docker push $targetacr/$image:{{.Tag}}" | bash
```

or using shell:

```
docker images $sourceacr/$image  --filter "since=$sourceacr/$image:$minimum_version" --format "docker tag {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} $targetacr/$image:{{.Tag}} | docker push $targetacr/$image:{{.Tag}}" | sh
```

Comment: Thanks but i still get similar output but with | Bash

Comment: Can you please edit your original post with the command and output from your shell?

Comment: The output looks correct. So you're saying with the | bash is not executing the output commands?

Comment: yes correct.  it just gives me additional | bash in my output but doesn't execute them.

Comment: My apologies, I had included the | bash between the double quotes for the --format field. I edited my post with the correct formatting. Can you please try again and let me know?

Comment: thanks much . it worked. ( i am using shell so i have added | sh)